# Multiple regression with a blockwise manner vs simple multiple regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, spss, r-squared

Almost all papers I read (in social science) used multiple regression in a "blockwise" manner instead of including all variables at once. I was wondering if it's even possible in our field to not go with the flow and do a multiple regression which includes all variables at once. I know with doing so we won't be able to calculate R-squared of each variable but is it even a problem? Do journals editors care about the exact R-squared of each variable or is it also OK to employ a multiple regression and just have the R-squared of overall model not each variable?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to try to speak for journal editors, but since you put an SPSS tag on this, I'll note that there's a way in the REGRESSION procedure to get the R<sup>2</sup> addition of each predictor on top of all others in a given model. Suppose you have y as the dependent and x1, x2, and x3 as independents. A command like the following will give these results:

REGRESSION
  /DEPENDENT y
  /METHOD=TEST (x1) (x2) (x3).

Look for the Subset Tests section of the ANOVA table.

Comment: Nice to see you on this site, @David Nichols.

Answer (score 0):

Another useful statistic is the (squared) semipartial  correlation: in SPSS, “/stat zpp”.  This tells the unique contribution of each predictor to R-squared.